# C# linq query with where subquery for each property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this table:

[image]

I want to do a linq query where I'll get each property value based on the adminfilterfieldid.

I have this so far:

```
newDto = from d in DbContext.AdminFilterItems
         where d.AdminFilterID == filterId
         select new ReservationDto
         {
             BookingDate = d.Value
         };
```

Now since BookingDate is AdminFilterFieldId is 2, I was hoping I can do something like `BookingDate = d.Value.Where(s => s.AdminFilterFieldID = 3)` or null in case there is no value for that adminfilterfieldid.
I want to do this for all the fields for that adminfilterid.

Is that achievable somehow with this kind of query or will I need to do multiple queries?

Comment: You would need to either use Reflection to enumerating through the class (model) properties or create an interface that matches a string property name to the property in the class.

Comment: `d.Value` is a single row value, not a group. You would either need to group on `AdminFilterID` or put the `where` before the `select` to only pull the rows, possibly with a `.DefaultIfEmpty()` on the whole query for when no `AdminFilterFieldID` with value `3` exists. This seems like a poor database design ill-suited for a relational database (unless there is a compelling reason to use it - e.g. it is possible to have multiple duplicate `AdminFilterFieldID`s.)

Comment: @NetMage there are multiple filter fields http://prntscr.com/vq1vl3, now since I'm building up a query to execute I'll need to check if either the value exists for that search field or its null. Thx for your comments

Comment: But unless the filter fields are dynamic, you could just use a conventional SQL table with one column per filter field. Do you create filter fields on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks simple enough just another clause in your where.

```
from d in DbContext.AdminFilterItems
         where d.AdminFilterID == filterId
         && d.AdminFilterFieldID = 3
         select new ReservationDto
         {
             BookingDate = d.Value
         };
```

If you need to filter it on multiple values just keep your initial query and run other filters on it then do your projection (select).

```
var qry =  from d in DbContext.AdminFilterItems
             where d.AdminFilterID == filterId
// Filter 1
qry.Where(d => d.AdminFilterFieldID = 3).Select(d => new ReservationDto
             {
                 BookingDate = d.Value
             });

// Filter 2
qry.Where(d => d.AdminFilterFieldID = 2).Select(d => new ReservationDto
             {
                 BookingDate = d.Value
             });
```